# Jquery to create a pushdown div effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, user-interface

I am trying to build a functionality similar to this site. where on clicking the "How it works" link it pushes down a div with some marketing material:

https://prescreen.com/?ui=logo

wondering if you have a clue about a jQuery that I can use for this effect.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the effect you want?

Comment: click on "How it works" link on the page : https://prescreen.com/?ui=logo

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. slidetoggle would be suitable for you indeed.

Answer (score 6):

Dan from Prescreen here. I helped write that nifty little container you are referring to.

Everyone is on the right track, it's pretty simple. Here is the exact transition configuration we used to show and hide the entire element:

```
//show the element
element.slideDown(1800, 'easeOutBounce');

//hide the element (note we sped up the hide to get it out of users way ASAP)
element.slideUp(800, 'easeOutExpo');
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

The slideshow functionality inside was done first by setting up a parent "container" with the CSS property "overflow: hidden". Then a long chain of slides in a parent wrapper with the id "slideTrack". I think J. Smart finalized how this worked in the end. Here is the general idea:

```
<style>
  #container {
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .slideTrack {
    width: 10000px;
  }
  .slide {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  .slide1 {
    left: 0px;
  }
  .slide2 {
    left: 900px;
  }
  .slide3 {
    left: 1800px;
  }
</style>

<div id="container" style="overflow:hidden">
  <div id="slideTrack">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1"> slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide2"> slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide3"> slide 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery function 'animate', http://api.jquery.com/animate/, was used to animate a CSS transition. Using -= and += is a handy way to change the css value by an increment rather than by a whole value. Here is what we used:

```
//move right 
$(".slide").animate({ left: '-=900px'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
//move left 
$(".slide").animate({ left: '+=900px'}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
```

Cheers, hope that saves you some time and gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Steve's answer, you can add an easing type to the `.slideToggle()` function call to make the animation appear as though it is bouncing:

```
$('.toggledDiv').slideToggle('slow', 'easeOutBounce');
```

This requires including the jQuery Easing Plugin: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ANFRD/1/

Comment: try `$('.toggledDiv').stop().slideToggle('slow', 'easeOutBounce');` to prevent annoying animation queue...

Comment: @Paulooze You have to be careful using `.stop()` when you aren't setting definite ending points for your animation. For example if you add `.stop()` to my code and click really fast a few times, the element won't expand to it's full height anymore and can actually appear "broken." You can fix that by the implementation of `.stop()` or by the implementation of the animation.

Comment: Indeed, thank you! But imho it is better if element doesnt expand, than it would animate endlessly. User can still click "normally" and everything would be ok.

Comment: @Paulooze The best is if the animation code just animates to two absolute values so `.stop()` can work smoothly: http://jsfiddle.net/ANFRD/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) functionality

EDIT:

Here is an example of how it could be done: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANFRD/)

Comment: would it pushd own all the other div on the page. (thats the effect i want)

Comment: To make sure the other content is pushed down, you just need to make sure the div had normal positioning (ie. not position:absolute).

Comment: @Abhi - Random question: Have you tried it? If so, what did you see?  Did it work?

Comment: @Steve : hey Steve, thanks for suggestion and i tried implementing this here : http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/home.php  .. but does not seem to work.. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI provides different types of effects and has various easing options. You can try them from the link and I guess you're talking about "bounce" effect.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/